# php startup: intl: unable to initialize module

Tags: magento2, php

Actual problem - Magento - No images (might be css too)
I checked for image paths. The "adminhtml" directory inside pub/static is empty.
I tried reinstallation of magento, xampp and all. But nothing is working.

[image]

To get the adminhtml folder contents, i am using following method.

I was trying to run **"php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy"** command through command prompt. But i got this error.

[image]

Current System :-
PHP 5.6.15,
magento 2.x,
windows 8

Please give me the solution. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You download intl extension for wrong version of php. You php is 5.6 but looks like the extension is for php 5.5. Please try use proper version.

Answer (score 0):

You are running `php bin/magento` from within the `bin` folder. It should be just `magento`.